# Open Source Projects For Students

Tags: java, c++, open-source

I am a student of Information Technology. I think I am fairly comfortable with the Java and C++ languages. The next step I want to take towards honing my skills is to involve myself in some Open Source Project. The problem is that most of the projects seem to be too huge and scary to someone like me who is still in the learning phase. I tried Google for simple projects that students like me can participate in but unfortunately I was unable to find anything interesting.

Can someone please suggest some Open Source Software Projects for students that can help expose students to real world programming in general?

EDIT: The question was blocked, so let me rephrase it:
**How can a student gain real life experiences in Open Source Projects? How to find/select an Open Source Project for oneself?**

Comment: gihub may be a good place to start

Comment: I think you should start with what ever interests you.  You are not going to find a project which was designed for students, is interesting and everyone knows about but for some reason no-one has worked on leaving all the really simple things for you to do. You can start as simple as fixing typos in documentation, or adding to documentation, or adding test cases.  In fact I would love it if more people did really basic stuff like that for my open source projects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just not be afraid of trying yourself somewhere. You have 4 ways:

1. Google Summer of Code
2. github/bitbucket, other open repositories where you can participate very easily.
3. Huge communities like GNOME, KDE, and etc.
4. It is very easy to start your own open-source project and this would very good for your CV.

Opensource called so because everyone can participate.

So, IMO, your first and last problem is your fear.

P.S. It is not dependent on your skill. Anyway, I guess I know what are you seeking for - `junior jobs`.

Junior jobs exist almost in each opensource project, but if not - it is easy to explain what it is: junior jobs may be: fixes for minor bugs, typos in the code and other minor changes. After you/project mentor realized that you have enough skills then you/project mentor may ask/give you full repository access to contribute. In other way, you simply can contact project maintainer to ask how you can help to improve this project.

And last - you can simply write documentation for the code, wiki-pages and etc, because each project needs documentation updates or even writing it from scratch.

Comment: All I am able to find on searching is how to start or join a project. What I am specifically looking for is a project suitable for beginners.

Comment: @CrystalMeth All projects are suitable for beginners. What is the worst thing that will happen? No-one is going to die.

Comment: @Crystal Meth, I've edited my answer accordingly this your question.

Answer (score 1):

I think, the best for You is creating own project. Create group student who want learn by creating. This is probabli better option for You. Don't scare. Many people start like You:) Good luck!

Comment: Honestly this is a mixed idea at best. They will learn far more by seeing what and how an established project works, the trouble is finding a place to get started.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question but unfortunately asked in the wrong place, it's off topic for stack overflow.

Your best bet may be to find one of the more modular projects like for example jME3 and get involved there. You can start of writing something basic using the library, then maybe develop a plugin or enhancement and share it back to the community, and then gradually work your way up from there.

Comment: I am sorry if this question is off topic, but I don't know where else I can post it.